# How to change date format in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am getting date format of *Wed May 06 20:00:00 EDT 2015*. I want to change it to *yyyy/MM/dd* format in groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').format(my_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you're looking for:

```
new Date().format('yyyy/MM/dd')
```

?

Comment: I believe you also have to showcase use of `Date.parse().format()` because it is not 8 PM EDT yet here in EDT. :)